# System close icon looks like outlined

Tags: android, icons, material-design

I am using this icon in my code:
android.R.drawable.ic_menu_close_clear_cancel

But it looks outlined, not simple cross:

[image]

I want to make it like this: https://storage.googleapis.com/spec-host-backup/mio-design%2Fassets%2F1Xlq7_lXkjBJDE6arihpaS3YWm4TSf2-S%2Fdialogs-fullscreen-behavior.mp4
Should I use another resource or tinting?

Comment: You want it with a different color?

Comment: Can you paste your menu.xml and your MainActivity.java please?

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS, I want to make it like this: https://storage.googleapis.com/spec-host-backup/mio-design%2Fassets%2F1Xlq7_lXkjBJDE6arihpaS3YWm4TSf2-S%2Fdialogs-fullscreen-behavior.mp4

Answer (score -1):

You can do it either way but Android advices against using platform resource ids. You can copy the icon into your drawables and use that resource id instead (and in your case tint it).

Android docs about the matter: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_menu

> Warning: Because these resources can change between platform versions, you should not reference these icons using the Android platform resource IDs (i.e. menu icons under android.R.drawable). If you want to use any icons or other internal drawable resources, you should store a local copy of those icons or drawables in your application resources, then reference the local copy from your application code. In that way, you can maintain control over the appearance of your icons, even if the system's copy changes. Note that the grid below is not intended to be complete.

Comment: I am about icon appearance. It looks outlined. But in material guides icon looks solid without outlining.